# Weierstrass Approximation-- Rudin's Proof

Tags: analysis

1) In Rudin's proof towrds the end, he declares that $4M\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot(1-\delta^2)^n$ goes to zero as n goes to infinity.  I just don't see it though -- how is this the case.

2) My second question is that  Rudin replaces $f_n(x + t) - f(x) \leq 2\sup(f(x))$.  How did he come up with this?

Answer (score 0):

For (1), use $1-\delta^2\leqslant\mathrm e^{-\delta^2}$ and $\delta^2n\leqslant\mathrm e^{\delta^2n}$ to deduce
$$
4M\sqrt{n}(1-\delta^2)^n\leqslant4M\delta^{-1}\sqrt{\delta^2n}\cdot\mathrm e^{-n\delta^2}\leqslant4M\delta^{-1}\sqrt{\mathrm e^{\delta^2n}}\cdot\mathrm e^{-n\delta^2}=C\,r^n,
$$
with
$$
C=4M\delta^{-1},\qquad r=\mathrm e^{-\delta^2/2}\lt1.
$$
And (2) might be a straightforward consequence of the inequalities $$
f_n(x+t)-f(x)\leqslant|f_n(x+t)|+|f(x)|\leqslant\|f_n\|_\infty+\|f\|_\infty.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!  My difficulty with (1), though, was seeing how the limit of 4M*sqrt(n)*(1-delta^2)^n as n goes to infinity is zero.

Comment: Why *though*? My answer shows the limit is zero.

Comment: You're right, it does-- I see it's trivial now.  Thank you so much!